# how decrease click for opening contact in Android

Tags: android, permissions, contacts

I'm new to android. I want to open contacts after getting permission. My problem is at start I need to click the button tow time, one for getting permission and one for opening contacts.

Is there any way to open contacts immediately after getting permission without any need for 2nd click

Comment: do you try to add your action in your onRequestPermissionsResult?

Comment: yes, the way is to run your code in place, where you get callback of the permissions granted

Answer (score 1):

yes you can handle request permission result like this

**1.ask permission in button click event**

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String permission = android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SearchCityClass.this, permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SearchCityClass.this, new String[]
                        {permission}, PERMISSION_CODE);

            } else {
                    isPermissionGranted(true);                  

            }
        }

    });
```

**2. handle permission result in onRequestPermissionsResult**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


             isPermissionGranted(true);        

        } else {

             isPermissionGranted(false);        
        }
    }

}
```

**3.now create a method for like this**

```
public void isPermissionGranted(boolean permission) {
    if (!permission) {
      // permission not granted
    } else {
     // add here your code beacuse permisiion is granted
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you try to get permission, you call a function and tell your requirement. (only dangerous permission needed to get permission)
after that when the user accept or reject, it come to **onRequestPermissionsResult**.

inside this method you can check if you gain the permission, do your action.

```
         @Override
         public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            if (Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //do your action 
         }
```

hope to help you